# SQL EXIST statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

LibraryDB is a database system that keeps track of information concerning the books and their circulation in an imaginary library.

The schema for the LibraryDB database is given below:

```
- borrow(transactionID, personID*, borrowdate, duedate, returndate) 
- author(authorID, firstname, middlename, lastname)
- book_copy(bookID, bookdescID*)
- book(bookdescID, title, subtitle, edition, voltitle, volnumber, language, place, year, isbn, dewey, subjectID*)
- borrow_copy(transactionID*, bookID*)
- person(personID, firstname, middlename, lastname, address, city, postcode, phonenumber, emailaddress, studentno, idcardno)
- publisher(publisherID, publisherfullname) 
- written_by(bookdescID*, authorID*, role) 
- published_by(bookdescID*, publisherID*, role) 
- subject(subjectID, subjecttype)
```

The primary keys are underlined. The foreign keys are denoted by asterisks (*).

Write SQL queries for the following tasks:

Display full names of publishers with whom the author Alfred Aho published his book(s). Your query must use EXISTS clause.

Comment: Why do you want to use exists here?

Comment: @RajivShah I want to know how EXISTS works.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Yes.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data examples, and knowledge about collations in the database; the request for SQL92 standard look like is:

```
    SELECT publisherfullname FROM publisher p
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM author a
            INNER JOIN written_by wb ON (a.authorID = wb.authorID)
            INNER JOIN published_by pb ON (wb.bookdescID = pb.bookdescID)
        WHERE
            UPPER(a.firstname) = 'ALFRED' AND
            UPPER(a.lastname) = 'AHO' AND
            pb.publisherID = p.publisherID
    )
```

But if collations in the database are case insensitive; request can be easy:

```
    SELECT publisherfullname FROM publisher p
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM author a
            INNER JOIN written_by wb ON (a.authorID = wb.authorID)
            INNER JOIN published_by pb ON (wb.bookdescID = pb.bookdescID)
        WHERE
            a.firstname = 'ALFRED' AND
            a.lastname = 'AHO' AND
            pb.publisherID = p.publisherID
    )
```

But in real-world most developers thinking about 'LIKE' operator, because real search from web requests, use partial match.

So if it query for search from the web form it looks like this, without case insensitive collations:

```
    SELECT publisherfullname FROM publisher p
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM author a
            INNER JOIN written_by wb ON (a.authorID = wb.authorID)
            INNER JOIN published_by pb ON (wb.bookdescID = pb.bookdescID)
        WHERE
            UPPER(a.firstname) LIKE '%ALFRED%' AND
            UPPER(a.lastname) LIKE '%AHO%' AND
            pb.publisherID = p.publisherID
    )
```

With case insensitive collations for columns firstname and lastname:

```
    SELECT publisherfullname FROM publisher p
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM author a
            INNER JOIN written_by wb ON (a.authorID = wb.authorID)
            INNER JOIN published_by pb ON (wb.bookdescID = pb.bookdescID)
        WHERE
            a.firstname LIKE '%ALFRED%' AND
            a.lastname LIKE '%AHO%' AND
            pb.publisherID = p.publisherID
    )
```

Comment: Could you please clarify whether `SELECT 1` is the same as `SELECT *` here?

Comment: Yep, absolutely, the same behaviour. But the query optimizer generates a bit more optimized plan if we use 1 instead of *.

Comment: Why did you use `a.firstname LIKE 'Alfred' ` instead of `a.firstname = 'Alfred' `? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yep, you are absolutely right, if we use certain equality; it's generated more preferred executing plan than like. I'll correct the answer. Usage ```LIKE``` create more naturally query; because search by names, usually used in form ```LIKE 'Jo%'```

Comment: Yep, It's a usual story. Please check that author firstname and lastname; It's must be absolutely the same that in the database. Or we can modify the query; For example add trim function for trimming spaces after and before names. `TRIM(a.firstname) = 'Alfred' AND
        TRIM(a.lastname) = 'Aho' `

Comment: I found that when I executed the query with LIKE in SQLite it returned 1 row, but when I executed the query that replaces `LIKE` with `=` it returned no result. This was because there was a row in the author table whose values for the firstname column and the lastname column are "ALFRED" and "AHO" respectively. Therefore using the statement `a.firstname = 'Alfred'` returned no result, while using the statement `a.firstname = 'ALFRED'` or `a.firstname LIKE 'Alfred'` returned one row. Please correct the `'Alfred'` and `'Aho'` to `'ALFRED'` and `'AHO'` respectively. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sure. I'll correct the response for insensitive case comparison. Thanks.

Comment: Simply saying `a.firstname = 'ALFRED'` and `a.lastname = 'AHO'` would be much simpler and easier to understand. If these statements are no different in effect to yours that use the `TRIM` clause, then could you please change your answer to statements with  `a.firstname = 'ALFRED'` and `a.lastname = 'AHO'`? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer and reply to my comments. I appreciate your effort.